# ant build.xml filename without file (base name of the file) only .(dot) and extension

Tags: ant, filenames, radix, build.xml, fileset

I have in ant build.xml directive

```
<target name="war" depends="compile">
        <war destfile="dist/app.war" webxml="WebContent/WEB-INF/web.xml">
            <fileset dir="WebContent">
                <include name="**/*.*"/>
                <include name="._arrow.png"/>
            </fileset>
            <lib dir="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib"/>
            <classes dir="build/classes"/>
        </war>
    </target>
```

in the war file I got only :

```
favicon.ico
robots.txt
sitemap.xml
```

I am unable to add the files without base name of the file and who has only .extention like

```
._arrow.png
```

Can someone help me, please?

Thanks Raul

Comment: Are you absolutely sure you're able to view hidden files wherever you're verifying the contents of the war? Starting a file with a `.` is the UNIX standard for hidden mode. Also, can you list the contents of `WebContent` for reference?

Comment: 20/08/2020  09:14    <DIR>          .elasticbeanstalk
20/08/2020  09:14           113,430 ._antreprenoriat.png
20/08/2020  09:14           111,382 ._arrow-left.png

Comment: and inside the war is missing :20/08/2020  09:51    <DIR>          META-INF
20/08/2020  09:14               114 robots.txt
20/08/2020  09:14            36,613 sitemap.xml
20/08/2020  09:51    <DIR>          stylesheet
20/08/2020  09:51    <DIR>          WEB-INF